# How to get the result based on a condition in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below dataframe with me

```
+---+-----+---+
| ID|Month|val|
+---+-----+---+
| M1|  Jan| 10|
| M1|  Feb| 20|
| M1|  Mar| 30|
| M2|  Jan| 22|
| M2|  Feb| 33|
| M3|  Jan| 30|
| M3|  Feb| 30|
| M4|  Jan| 40|
| M4|  Feb| 39|
+---+-----+---+
```

created by -

```
val df1=Seq(
("M1","Jan","10"),
("M1","Feb","20"),
("M1","Mar","30"),
("M2","Jan","22"),
("M2","Feb","33"),
("M3","Jan","30"),
("M3","Feb","30"),
("M4","Jan","40"),
("M4","Feb","39")
).toDF("ID","Month","val")
```

I have to find out those row whose val are lesser than or equal to the previous months.

Expected Result -

```
+---+-----+---+-------+
| ID|Month|val|    Res|
+---+-----+---+-------+
| M1|  Jan| 10| true  |
| M1|  Feb| 20| true  |
| M1|  Mar| 30| true  |
| M2|  Jan| 22| true  |
| M2|  Feb| 33| true  |
| M3|  Jan| 30| true  |
| M3|  Feb| 30| false |
| M4|  Jan| 40| true  |
| M4|  Feb| 39| false |
+---+-----+---+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag` over a window ordered by the month converted to a date:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df2 = df1.withColumn(
    "Res",
    coalesce(
        $"val" > lag($"val", 1).over(Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy(to_date($"Month", "MMM"))),
        lit(true)
    )
).orderBy($"ID", to_date($"Month", "MMM"))

df2.show
+---+-----+---+-----+
| ID|Month|val|  Res|
+---+-----+---+-----+
| M1|  Jan| 10| true|
| M1|  Feb| 20| true|
| M1|  Mar| 30| true|
| M2|  Jan| 22| true|
| M2|  Feb| 33| true|
| M3|  Jan| 30| true|
| M3|  Feb| 30|false|
| M4|  Jan| 40| true|
| M4|  Feb| 39|false|
+---+-----+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Using spark-sql,

```
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")

spark.sql(""" select ID ,Month, val, 
case 
when lag(val) over(partition by id order by to_date(month,'MMM') ) is null then 'true'
when val > coalesce(lag(val) over(partition by id order by to_date(month,'MMM') ),val) then 'true'
else 'false' end
as Res
from df1
order by id, to_date(month,'MMM')
""").show(false)

+---+-----+---+-----+
|ID |Month|val|Res  |
+---+-----+---+-----+
|M1 |Jan  |10 |true |
|M1 |Feb  |20 |true |
|M1 |Mar  |30 |true |
|M2 |Jan  |22 |true |
|M2 |Feb  |33 |true |
|M3 |Jan  |30 |true |
|M3 |Feb  |30 |false|
|M4 |Jan  |40 |true |
|M4 |Feb  |39 |false|
+---+-----+---+-----+
```